# How can I make a query that ignores the first two rows when I create a connection between workbooks

Tags: excel, powerquery

I want to automate the process of creating a weekly report but the first row contains a timestamp that messes up my query connection.

Here is how my source spreadsheet looks [source data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loKuD.jpg)

My problem is that when I **Get Data From Workbook** Excel takes these first two rows into account. Like that [source data preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/955xD.jpg)

Because this value is unique with each report when I replace source data to get my polished report I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJHYl.jpg) error after refreshing the query connection.

I could manually cut and paste these two rows every time but as I mentioned above I hope to optimize the process as much as possible so modifying the source data each time is not my desired problem solution.

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is to delete the step that changes the type of the columns

[image: Delete step]

After that, select from the ribbon "Remove rows" | "Remove top rows"

[image: Remove rows]

And then enter "2"

[image: Enter 2]

Then, optionally, select "Use first rows as headers"

[image: Use first rows]

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly! Is there a way to replace the value in the first row without messing up the query? (Actually keeping first two rows, just replacing the value in A1)

Comment: More specifically, is there a way to keep the first two rows as default cells (while replacing A1 with a new value when the data source is changed) and formatting the rest (below row 2) as a table?

Comment: Replacing the value of the first "cell" is doable, but I don't understand what you mean about formatting the rest as a table...

Comment: The problem with keeping the first two rows when transforming the data is that the whole thing is formatted as a table (I need col1, col2, col3... as table headers, not as values in a table)

Comment: I managed to deal with that by creating two separate queries, one where I used the "drill down" option on the A1 cell and extracted the value as a table. The second query is the one mentioned above in the verified answer. I also hid the first row for aesthetic purposes (the first row is the one with the column name for the first query)